# Determine if a Teams meeting started

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there a way to get information about Teams meeting being started? Maybe some event is raised or it can be achieved with a webhook?

If that's not supported, then maybe a walkaround with checking if people are attending certain meeting?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/18979909-meeting-reminders) on this. You can upvote if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Comment: This user voice is not what I had in mind. I want to have a possibility to know if a online meeting created in teams is being in progress at a given time. I imagine it to be something like state property for a call described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/call?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can check users current status via API. There is property `InACall`.
More on that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/presence?view=graph-rest-beta).

Comment: Thank you, but thats not what Im looking for. I would like to know if a person is present on a specific call. This API returns only a status.